# Joomla Custom Component

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-component

I have successfully built my own custom joomla component from scratch, but I am stuck on a presumably relatively simple problem.

For the purpose of this example lets say that:

A equals Home page

B equals Player(Multiple) list page

C equals Player(Individual) page

I have so far got part A and C working. I can get to my individual player page by entering in their id into the url.

[Example of part C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlJAG.png)

What I am unsure about now is creating a view before this when you click on the players menu button that it directs you to a view which displays a list of all players. I have already created a function within the model which returns all players in the database for the purpose of this view. I can upload my component or paste any of my code into this post if needed.

I did follow [Joomla component](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5/Developing_a_Basic_Component) on how to create a component so I presume I have the default settings for my component.

Comment: just create another view, i am not sure where is the problem?

Comment: Like Marco D said, create another view, then link to your detail view in the actual page. That's generally how listings/detail pages work.

Answer (score 0):

You can at an extra public function in your controller this one get available as "task" and can be accessed like this:

/index.php?option=com_name-of-component&view=view-to-load&format=raw&task=name-of-function

If this function get's to big you can create a multi controller component. I can not explain better than this:

[Using Multiple Controllers in Joomla Component Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606010/using-multiple-controllers-in-joomla-component-development)

Answer (score 0):

If you build your component in the [Component Creator for Joomla](http://www.component-creator.com), you can probably just use the component it makes for you or you can view the code it generates and copy paste (or at least learn) from the code generated.